# How can I do work __set__ or __setattr__ with including class?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

So, I have a class that describe some page object, something like this:

```
class Dashboard:
    project_edit_modal = Modal({
        "edit_input": Input(
            by=By.XPATH,
            value='//div[@class="header"][text()="Project edit"]',
            name='Title \'Project edit\''),
         "some_input: Input ()....
    )}
```

Here "Input" - this is the class with selectors how to find elements. And "Modal" - is the class where collect this Inputs and other modal windows elements.

I have descriptor `__set__`inside the "Modal".
Now, when I want to type in "edit_input" I can white something like this:

```
Dashboard().Modal().edit_input = 'some value'.
```

I suppose that `__set__` or `__setattr__` will called, and type into "edit_input", but doesnt(
`__set__` calling only if you white something like this

```
Dashboard().Modal() = 'some value'.
```

But I need:

```
Dashboard().Modal().edit_input = 'some value'.
```

But how can I do work this construction with "Modal" class?

Code is here:

```
class Modal:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if isinstance(args[0], dict):
            self.values = args[0]
            self.elements = self.values.keys()

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
          el: WebElement = Browser().get_element(selector_type=self._selector_type, selector=self._selector)
            el.send_keys(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a major misconception there, and I won't have the time or proper explaining it.

Buit in short, doing `Dashboard().Modal()` does not make any sense - if you had `Modal` - the class itself, not an instance of it - as an attribute of a `Dashboard` instance, then this would create you a fresh new instance of `Modal`, with no bindings to the `Dashboard` at all.

The binding behavior of the descriptor protocol, which makes Python call `__get__` and `__set__` methods takes place when you have an *instance* of your descriptor class set as a *class attribute* of the hosting class.
This is what your code snippet is doing correctly with the `project_edit_modal` attribute.

So, if the remaining of your code is well formed, your `__set__` method will be called if you do:

```
Dashboard().project_edit_modal = 'some value'
```

Comment: Yes, I understood what you tell me about, I had in Error - I need construct like this:
Dashboard().project_edit_modal.edit_input = 'some value'
But I cant do this work.
I need set modals windows description in other element on the common Dashboard page, and in the test function write like this:
Dashboard().project_edit_modal.edit_input = 'some value'
I cant to call __ set__ or __seattribute_ _ when this code calls.
Maybe is there other way to do it?

Comment: Then edit_input have to be an object of a class with `__set__` and be an attribute on `Modal`. The `__get__`/ `__set__` behavior only works for the innermost attribute (the last dot) in a nested attribute chain.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but in this case I have to do dynamically method __set__ for all elements of "project_edit_modal", like "edit_input" etc (here may be many elements). And this is I have to do during starting my test framework? Because when in code are implement string like this "Dashboard().project_edit_modal.edit_input = 'some value' " - into "edit_input" object must be method __set__, right?

Comment: If you have a lot of attributes in a class you want to give an specific behavior - including code to be run at setting the attribute with a `__set__` method, there are 3 good options, after you design one or more descriptor classes with the `__set__` method that will attend you: you can just declare the attributes and transform then with either a metaclass, a base class with a `__init_subclass__` method, or a class decorator.

Comment: Thank you dear! I am breaking my brain how to do it... I am trying some ways you say